# How to create a hyperlink in dialogflow as response from fulfilment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to create a hyperlink in fulfillment and send it as a response to the to render on the GUI.

Any help on how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: for better result you can create your custome chat window

Comment: I agree, but it's just for the tutorial of dialogflow that I am trying to learn